# Extract a bit sequence from a character

Tags: c, binary, character, ascii, bit

So I have an array of characters like the following {h,e,l,l,o,o}
so I need first to translate this to its bit representation, so what I would have is this

```
h = 01101000
e = 01100101
l = 01101100
l = 01101100
o = 01101111
o = 01101111
```

I need divide all of this bits in groups of five and save it to an array
so for example the union of all this characters would be

```
011010000110010101101100011011000110111101101111
```

And now I divide this in groups of five so

```
01101 00001 10010 10110 11000 11011 00011 01111 01101 111
```

and the last sequence should be completed with zeros so it would be 00111 instead. Note: Each group of 5 bits would be completed with a header in order to have 8 bits.

So I havent realized yet how to accomplish this, because I can extract the 5 bits of each character and get the representation of each character  in binary as following

```
 for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
  {
     printf("%c", (c & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0');
  }
```

The problem is how to combine two characters so If I have two characters 00000001 and 11111110 when I divide in five groups I would have 5 bits of the first part of the character and for the second group I would have 3 bits from the last character and 2 from the second one. How can I make this combination and save all this groups in an array?

Comment: The thing that you want to achieve doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is almost the same as base64. Base64 stores 6 bits per character. Much like what you want except base64 collects the extra 2 bits from every 3 bytes and makes each 4th byte using the 6 extra bits from the previous 3 bytes.

Comment: @doug65536 To each group of 5 bits I would add a header to complete the 8 bits, the thing is that I cant figure out how to get all this five groups

Comment: Can't you just build a string by concatenating the results of `'h' = "01101000" ....` and then taking the characters in groups of five until there are fewer than 5 left, padding the final group.

Comment: @ravelinx You should say that you want to add a header. You will want to make a byte from the appropriate number of bytes. What would be the header that you want?

Comment: @iharob Ok, I have modified my question, but the thing is that adding the header is not the problem for me, the thing is dividing the bits in groups

Comment: @DavidBowling How can I achieve this in c?

Comment: A loop, some variables to keep track of the bit offsets, some shifting and masking, and an output buffer.

Comment: @ravelinx-- I added an answer that you should be able to use. You can probably clean up the code a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a byte is made of 8 bits (*ATTENTION: the C standard doesn't guarantee this*),  you have to loop over the string and play with bit operations to get it done:

- `>> n`  right shift to get rid of the n lowest bits
- `<< n`  to inject n times a 0 bit in the lowest position
- `& 0x1f`  to keep only the 5 lowest bits and reset the higer bits
- `|`     to merge high bits and low bits, when the overlapping bits are 0

This can be coded like this:

```
char s[]="helloo";

unsigned char last=0;          // remaining bits from previous iteration in high output part
size_t j=5;                    // number of high input bits to keep in the low output part 
unsigned char output=0; 
for (char *p=s; *p; p++) {     // iterate on the string 
    do {
        output = ((*p >> (8-j)) | last) & 0x1f;  // last high bits set followed by j bits shifted to lower part; only 5 bits are kept 
        printf ("%02x ",(unsigned)output);
        j += 5;                                  // take next block  
        last = (*p << (j%8)) & 0x1f;             // keep the ignored bits for next iteration 
    } while (j<8);                               // loop if second block to be extracted from current byte
    j -= 8;                                      
}
if (j)                                           // there are trailing bits to be output
   printf("%02x\n",(unsigned)last);
```

[**online demo**](http://ideone.com/n7xsLO)

The displayed result for your example will be (in hexadecimal): `0d 01 12 16 18 1b 03 0f 0d 1c`, which corresponds exactly to each of the 5 bit groups that you have listed.  Note that this code ads 0 right padding in the last block if it is not exactly 5 bits long (e.g. here the last 3 bits are padded to 11100 i.e. 0x1C instead of 111 which would be 0x0B)

You could easily adapt this code to store the output in a buffer instead of printing it.  The only delicate thing would be to precalculate the size of the output which should be 8/5 times the original size, to be increased by 1 if it's not a multiple of 5 and again by 1 if you expect a terminator to be added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that should solve your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char arr[6] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'o'};
    char charcode[9];
    char binarr[121] = "";
    char fives[24][5] = {{0}};
    int i, j, n, numchars, grouping = 0, numgroups = 0;

    /* Build binary string */
    printf("\nCharacter encodings:\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for (i = 0, n = 7;  i < 8; i++, n--)
            charcode[i] = (arr[j] & (01 << n)) ? '1' : '0';
        charcode[8] = '\0';
        printf("%c = %s\n", arr[j], charcode);
        strcat(binarr, charcode);
    }

    /* Break binary string into groups of 5 characters */
    numchars = strlen(binarr);
    j = 0;
    while (j < numchars) {
        i = 0;
        if ((numchars - j) < 5) {                 // add '0' padding
            for (i = 0; i < (5 - (numchars - j)); i++)
                fives[grouping][i] = '0';
        }
        while (i < 5) {                           // write binary digits
            fives[grouping][i] = binarr[j];
            ++i;
            ++j;
        }
        ++grouping;
        ++numgroups;
    }

    printf("\nConcatenated binary string:\n");
    printf("%s\n", binarr);

    printf("\nGroupings of five, with padded final grouping:\n");
    for (grouping = 0; grouping <= numgroups; grouping++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            printf("%c", fives[grouping][i]);
        putchar(' ');
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

When you run this as is, the output is:

```
Character encodings:
h = 01101000
e = 01100101
l = 01101100
l = 01101100
o = 01101111
o = 01101111

Concatenated binary string:
011010000110010101101100011011000110111101101111

Groupings of five, with padded final grouping:
01101 00001 10010 10110 11000 11011 00011 01111 01101 00111
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define GROUP_SIZE 5

static int nextBit(void);
static int nextGroup(char *dest);

static char str[] = "helloo";

int main(void) {
    char bits[GROUP_SIZE + 1];
    int firstTime, nBits;

    firstTime = 1;
    while ((nBits = nextGroup(bits)) == GROUP_SIZE) {
        if (!firstTime) {
            (void) putchar(' ');
        }
        firstTime = 0;
        (void) printf("%s", bits);
    }
    if (nBits > 0) {
        if (!firstTime) {
            (void) putchar(' ');
        }
        while (nBits++ < GROUP_SIZE) {
            (void) putchar('0');
        }
        (void) printf("%s", bits);
    }
    (void) putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}

static int nextBit(void) {
    static int bitI = 0, charI = -1;

    if (--bitI < 0) {
        bitI = CHAR_BIT - 1;
        if (str[++charI] == '\0') {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return (str[charI] & (1 << bitI)) != 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

static int nextGroup(char *dest) {
    int bit, i;

    for (i = 0; i < GROUP_SIZE; ++i) {
        bit = nextBit();
        if (bit == -1) {
            break;
        }
        dest[i] = '0' + bit;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```